# How to prevent FastAPI from running init code twice?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a simple FastAPI app in a file `main.py` as follows:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

print('*' * 80)


@app.get("/")
async def index():
    return {"message": "Welcome to API!"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="localhost", port=8000)
```

I run the program by calling `python3 main.py`. I notice that the print statement gets executed twice:

```bash
python main.py
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
INFO:     Started server process [1024872]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://localhost:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

What can be done to prevent this? I have some rather expensive init code (like loading memory-intensive ML models) that I wouldn't like to see executed twice.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the startup/shutdown events? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/ - I'd also think you can also do the same as you do with `if __name__ == ` - just attach it in an `else:` clause below. The reason why this happens is because you run the code to start uvicorn, and uvicorn needs to run the application inside its environment as well. If you start uvicorn from the command line instead of through the Python script, you might have more luck (I don't remember if it ends up performing the import twice under those conditions)

Comment: I suggest you to use Dependency. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#create-a-dependency-or-dependable

Comment: @MatsLindh: Using `uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port <port>` does solve the problem, but I would like to run it as `python main.py` as being able to run it that way allows me to put debug points in PyCharm.

Comment: Then using an `else` clause or a startup event should solve that?

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thanks for the `uvicorn` suggestion, I am able to debug the app in PyCharm with that as well.